# Monitoring IIS servers

Tags: iis, monitoring

I have a few iis servers (windows 2003) I would like to monitor, and I would like the information presented in graph form if possible.

A couple of the servers i have full access into so I should be able to query using snmp, but some of them all I will have access to is the iis log files (not my kit).

I like some basic traffic info (connections/bandwidth etc) but also maybe something to monitor physical processors/ram usage on the internal ones i have full access to.

Any one point me at a good product

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good starting point for the servers you have direct access to is to work with Windows **Performance Monitor**. This MSDN article discusses which performance counters are most helpful in diagnosing stress and performance issues:

**[ASP.NET Performance Monitoring, and When to Alert Administrators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx)**

> There are many performance counters
>   available for monitoring applications.
>   Choosing which ones to include in
>   performance logs can be tricky, and
>   learning how to interpret them is an
>   art. This article should help you feel
>   more comfortable with both of these
>   tasks.

These are some interesting counters for IIS and ASP.NET:

- Processor:

  - % Processor Time
- Process (aspnet_wp)

  - % Processor Time
  - Private Bytes
  - Virtual Bytes
    -Handle Count
- Microsoft .NET CLR Exceptions\

  - ## Exceps thrown / sec
- ASP.NET

  - Application Restarts
  - Requests Rejected
- Memory

  - Available Mbytes
- Web Service

  - Current Connections
  - ISAPI Extension Requests/sec

For the sites you only have access to the IIS log files, I would use [**IIS Logparser**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) for analyzing possible problems or bottlenecks. There is a nice blog post on blogs.iis.net:

[**How To: IIS and Log Parser 2.2**](http://blogs.iis.net/ma_khan/archive/2009/03/19/how-to-iis-and-log-parser-2-2.aspx)

> As IIS administrators we come across
>   many scenarios wherein we are asked to
>   analyse the overall performance of a
>   web server. There are various steps
>   involved in it, however, analysing IIS
>   log files without a proper tool can be
>   a pain. It's very easy to get lost in
>   the lines. Log Parser is a tool that I
>   rely upon when it comes to manual IIS
>   log file analysis. It's a cool tool
>   that provides universal query access
>   to text-based data, such as .log
>   files.

Comment: Those are some good idea especially what pref counter to look at, but i was more aiming at something web based that would gather the stats every so often

Comment: Follow his advice to the letter for what to track, but instead of Perfmon, use Polymon to periodically gather the perfmon data, and display it for you in graphical form, notify you of a critical value, etc.  Polymon.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks for the info on PloyMon, never come across it before look like an interesting product

Answer (score 0):

System Center Operation Manager has a web based console and will generate reports.  Using an agent based product like SCOM might get you all the dta you want without havnig to have full access to the systems